# When creating new sharepoint modern team site, can i link it to existing office 365 group instead of linking it to the newly created group

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, team-sites, office-365-groups

I am working on SharePoint online , and when we create a new Team Site, as follow:-

[image]

It will always create a new office 365 group for us. but in our case we do not want to have a new Office 365 created for the new team site, instead we want to use existing office 365 group.. so is this possible to link our new team site to existing office 365 group? if this is possible then how we can do so ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to create new team site with existing Office 365 Group, every group contains one Dedicated SharePoint Root site with following URL https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/groupname.

But you have option to map your newly created team site email ID to existing Office 365 Group email ID [Article for setup the email ID](http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2017/02/07/changing-primary-email-address-office-group-365/)

Comment: i do not have to link the sharepoint team site with existing group from the beginning .. i mean i can create the sharepoint team site as is,, and got the new office 365 group created for us,, then later on to map the sharepoint site to existing group, and remove the newly created group ??is this possible ?

Comment: Nope, that's not possible. if you try to delete any office 365 group then it will delete all associated components like SharePoint Page, Exchange email ID.. So technically one office 365 group has one sharepoint site which could not map with any other office 365 group...